# How to run ssh -t user@remote 'sudo nohup bash -c "command"' in background

Tags: ssh, sudo, background-process, nohup

I want to run a script on a remote host with `sudo` privilege,
someone suggests that I should use `nohup` and `ssh -t`, like the following command:

The script `ls; sleep 10; echo finish` is crafted here to resemble what I want to do.

```
ssh -t esolve@remote_host \
'sudo nohup bash -c "ls;sleep 100;echo finish" < /dev/null 2>&1 >> ssh.log'
```

I want to run this script in background on local host 
because in my script, after this command there are some other commands, like

`my script.sh`:

```
ssh -t esolve@remote_host \
'sudo nohup bash -c "ls;sleep 100;echo finish" < /dev/null 2>&1 >> ssh.log' 
... some other commands
```

the following two commands don't work

```
ssh -t esolve@remote_host \
'sudo nohup bash -c "ls;sleep 100;echo finish" < /dev/null 2>&1 >> ssh.log' &

ssh -t esolve@remote_host \
'sudo nohup bash -c "ls;sleep 100;echo finish" < /dev/null 2>&1 >> ssh.log &'
```

Why?

And how can I make this command run in background of local host?
Besides, I don't need to input password for `sudo` on remote host.

Comment: Please add some more backround information. Do you want to run it in background of the localhost or remotehost? How are you authenticating with the remotehost, via public key or password?

Comment: The main problem seems to be how to run this command as superuser in backround without setting a password. Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4327123/1260906

Comment: You can also use screen to background stuff: `screen -d -m -S mybackgroundjob /usr/local/bin/somescript.sh`

Answer (score 4):

Add the `-b` flag to `sudo`, which prompts for password if needed and then goes to the background. (The redirect also needs to be done within bash) (Curly brackets are needed  to get the redirection to apply to everything)

```
ssh -t esolve@remote_host 'sudo -b nohup bash -c "{ ls;sleep 100;echo finish; } < /dev/null 2>&1 >> ssh.log"'
```

You might also want to try screen instead...

```
ssh -t esolve@remote_host 'sudo -b screen -m -d bash -c "{ ls;sleep 100;echo finish; } < /dev/null 2>&1 >> ssh.log"'
```